# Oracle: Unique Constraint violation on PK with verifiably unique data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to collect and store stats about many things where I work, and I'm suddenly having a problem with the process on one table in particular. The relevant part of the process for getting these stats involves just dumping data into a temp table and inserting any new data from that table into the main table. So I have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEMP_SCHEMA"."STATS_ORDERS"
(
  "ORDER_NO"      NUMBER(10,0)        NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "ORDER_DATE"    DATE                NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "ORDER_TYPE"    VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)    NOT NULL ENABLE
); /
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
ON "TEMP_SCHEMA"."STATS_ORDERS" TO "MY_SCHEMA"; /

CREATE TABLE "MY_SCHEMA"."STATS_ORDERS"
(
  "ORDER_NO"      NUMBER(10,0)        NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "ORDER_DATE"    DATE                NOT NULL ENABLE,
  "ORDER_TYPE"    VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)    NOT NULL ENABLE,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_STATS_ORDERS" PRIMARY KEY ("ORDER_NO", "ORDER_TYPE")
); /
```

After dumping the data into "TEMP_SCHEMA"."STATS_ORDERS" I'm trying something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS (ORDER_NO,ORDER_DATE,ORDER_TYPE)
SELECT
    DISTINCT TMP.ORDER_NO,TMP.ORDER_DATE,TMP.ORDER_TYPE
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TEMP_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS) TMP
    LEFT JOIN MY_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS ORD
    ON TMP.ORDER_NO = ORD.ORDER_NO AND TMP.ORDER_TYPE = ORD.ORDER_TYPE
WHERE ORD.ORDER_NO IS NULL AND ORD.ORDER_TYPE IS NULL; /
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (MY_SCHEMA.PK_STATS_ORDERS) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
          For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
          this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

I've run the following query to find which rows were causing the error:

```
SELECT ORDER_NO,ORDER_DATE,ORDER_TYPE
FROM
    MY_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS O
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT TMP.ORDER_NO,TMP.ORDER_DATE,TMP.ORDER_TYPE
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TEMP_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS) TMP
          LEFT JOIN MY_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS ORD
          ON TMP.ORDER_NO = ORD.ORDER_NO AND TMP.ORDER_TYPE = ORD.ORDER_TYPE
        WHERE ORD.ORDER_NO IS NULL AND ORD.ORDER_TYPE IS NULL
    ) N
    ON O.ORDER_NO = N.ORDER_NO AND O.ORDER_TYPE = N.ORDER_TYPE; /
```

Presumably this should return whatever rows are causing the violation, but of course it returns nothing because I explicitly exclude anything that could be a duplicate.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I accidentally left the original name in for my example. Changed it to the name in my example.

Comment: its probably duplicates in TEMP_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS (ie the same order no+type with different dates) and not something that is already present in MY_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS. ie run `select order_no, order_type, count(*) from temp_schema.stats_orders group by order_no, order_type having count(*) > 1`. do you get rows back?

Comment: Aha, I didn't think to look there. I wasn't "cleaning" out the old temp data before adding new data, and there was some overlap resulting in duplicate data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify you are not hitting this scenario:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE STATS_ORDERS_TMP
  2  (
  3    ORDER_NO      NUMBER(10,0)        NOT NULL ENABLE,
  4    ORDER_DATE    DATE                NOT NULL ENABLE,
  5    ORDER_TYPE    VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)    NOT NULL ENABLE
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE STATS_ORDERS
  2  (
  3    ORDER_NO      NUMBER(10,0)        NOT NULL ENABLE,
  4    ORDER_DATE    DATE                NOT NULL ENABLE,
  5    ORDER_TYPE    VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)    NOT NULL ENABLE,
  6    CONSTRAINT PK_STATS_ORDERS PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_NO, ORDER_TYPE)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into STATS_ORDERS_TMP values (1, sysdate, 'A');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into STATS_ORDERS_TMP values (1, sysdate-1, 'A');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into stats_orders (order_no,order_date,order_type)
  2  select
  3      distinct tmp.order_no,tmp.order_date,tmp.order_type
  4  from
  5      (select distinct * from stats_orders_tmp) tmp
  6      left join stats_orders ord
  7      on tmp.order_no = ord.order_no and tmp.order_type = ord.order_type
  8  where ord.order_no is null and ord.order_type is null;
insert into stats_orders (order_no,order_date,order_type)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DTD_TRADE.PK_STATS_ORDERS) violated
```

i.e. you have duplicate dates for a given order +type in the "temp" table.

your validation wouldnt see them (as they aren't in the main table):

```
SQL> SELECT o.ORDER_NO,o.ORDER_DATE,o.ORDER_TYPE
  2  FROM
  3      STATS_ORDERS O
  4      INNER JOIN (
  5          SELECT DISTINCT TMP.ORDER_NO,TMP.ORDER_DATE,TMP.ORDER_TYPE
  6          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM STATS_ORDERS_TMP) TMP
  7            LEFT JOIN STATS_ORDERS ORD
  8            ON TMP.ORDER_NO = ORD.ORDER_NO AND TMP.ORDER_TYPE = ORD.ORDER_TYPE
  9          WHERE ORD.ORDER_NO IS NULL AND ORD.ORDER_TYPE IS NULL
 10      ) N
 11      ON O.ORDER_NO = N.ORDER_NO AND O.ORDER_TYPE = N.ORDER_TYPE;

no rows selected
```

but they do exist:

```
SQL> select order_no, order_type, count(*) from stats_orders_tmp group by order_no, order_type having count(*) > 1;

  ORDER_NO O   COUNT(*)
---------- - ----------
         1 A          2
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest option to identify the problematic rows is generally to use [DML error logging](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2.php).  If you create the error table

```
BEGIN
  dmbs_errlog.create_error_log( dml_table_name => 'STATS_ORDERS',
                                err_log_table_name => 'STATS_ORDERS_ERR',
                                err_log_table_owner => 'MY_SCHEMA' );
END;
```

then you can use the `LOG ERRORS INTO` clause in your DML

```
INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS (ORDER_NO,ORDER_DATE,ORDER_TYPE)
  SELECT DISTINCT TMP.ORDER_NO,TMP.ORDER_DATE,TMP.ORDER_TYPE
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TEMP_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS) TMP
         LEFT JOIN MY_SCHEMA.STATS_ORDERS ORD
         ON TMP.ORDER_NO = ORD.ORDER_NO AND TMP.ORDER_TYPE = ORD.ORDER_TYPE
   WHERE ORD.ORDER_NO IS NULL AND ORD.ORDER_TYPE IS NULL
     LOG ERRORS INTO stats_orders_err
  REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

That will write any rows that are rejected by the constraint to the `stats_orders_err` error table.

Comment: This is great information to have! I'm sure I'll get a lot of use out of this (I'm not a DBA so much as a developer who was given a couple of schema's of my own to play around with)